# Pandas / Openpyxl : Write Dataframe with left corner on a specific cell

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to write a table in an excel sheet using openpyxl.

My Pandas Dataframe looklikes this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "A": [1, 3, 5],
   "B": [2, 4, 6],
})
```

I want to create a xlsx file that looklike this (Right corner of my dataframe in cell D9):

[image]

How could I do this, meaning is there a best way to do it by writing cell by cell using iteration an all dataframe ?
Thanks

Comment: [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) has `startrow` and `startcol` parameters

Comment: Thanks, but I have several dataframe and formating to do

Comment: I'm asking using openpyxl

Comment: If they are any dataframes (df) to be written to Excel it makes sense to use 'ExcelWriter' and 'to_excel' as suggested by @BigBen. You can write one or many dfs to the same or different sheets (using Openpyxl as the engine) in the one `to_excel` execution per df. Otherwise as @Laurent B.'s example you have to write each df value to the cell individually in a loop or maybe convert the df to lists and append row by row. Then after writing the data you will still have the ability to apply further formatting using Openpyxl if needed.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed code :**

Just play with `start_col` and `start_row`.

The function `get_column_letter` converts an integer column position into letters. let's say for instance `3` into `C` (starts from 1)

```py
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
"A": [1, 3, 5],
"B": [2, 4, 6],
})

# Create a new workbook and select the active sheet
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Define the range of cells to write the DataFrame
start_row = 9
start_col = 3

# Write DataFrame headers
for num, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    column_letter = openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(start_col+num)
    ws[f'{column_letter}{start_row}'] = col
    
# Write the DataFrame to the worksheet
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for col in range(len(row)):
        column_letter = openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(start_col+col)
        ws[f'{column_letter}{idx+start_row+1}'] = df.iloc[idx, col]

# Save the workbook to a file
wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

**Display**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Further to the comment, here is a self contained example of writing several dataframes to Excel on two different sheets.

In this example there are four dataframes, two are written to one sheet (Sheet1) and the other two to another sheet (Sheet2).
A dictionary is used to set what Sheet and the Top Left Cell for each Dataframe so all four can be added using a loop through the same `to_excel` code.

After the data is written, we can modify/format cells using Openpyxl, like fill cells or setting the number format.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill

### Create Dataframes

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 3, 5],
    "B": [2, 4, 6],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Andreas', 'George', 'Steve',
                              'Sarah', 'Joanna', 'Hanna'],
                    'Age': [21, 22, 20, 19, 18, 23]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Pete', 'Jordan', 'Gustaf',
                              'Sophie', 'Sally', 'Simone'],
                    'Age': [22, 21, 19, 19, 29, 21]})

df4 = pd.DataFrame({'Names': ['Ulrich', 'Donald', 'Jon',
                              'Jessica', 'Elisabeth', 'Diana'],
                    'Age': [21, 21, 20, 19, 19, 22]})

### Create a dictionary for each Dataframe location
dfs = {'Sheet1!B5': df1, 'Sheet1!E2': df2, 'Sheet2!D9': df3, 'Sheet2!H1': df4}

### Create writer
### Name of Excel workbook to write to. The xlsx file MUST EXIST already in the mode used here
### mode='a' sets the writer to append data to existing workbook
### if_sheet_exists='overlay' incorporates the data into the existing Sheet. The Sheet will be added if it doesn't exist.
with pd.ExcelWriter('newfile.xlsx', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    ### Get each dataframe details
    for location, df in dfs.items():  # Loop the dataframe dictionary
        ### Split for Sheet name and Dataframe co-ordinates
        sheet, coord = location.split('!')

        ### Write dataframe to Excel using Sheet and location extracted from the dictionary
        ### Dataframe Index is dropped, Header is retained.
        df.to_excel(writer,
                    sheet_name=sheet,
                    startrow=int(coord[-1:]) - 1,
                    startcol=int(openpyxl.utils.column_index_from_string(coord[:1])) - 1,
                    index=False)
        
        ### Use Openpyxl to add/change formatting of cells like fill colour or number format looping cells by whatever method
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
        for col in range(2,4):
            worksheet.cell(row=5, column=col).fill = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fill_type='solid', fgColor='D9D9D9')

        for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_col=2, min_row=6, max_col=2, max_row=8):
            worksheet[row[0].coordinate].number_format = '0.00'
```